# How do you turn off remote access to WAMP server

Tags: remote-access, wamp

so I clicked on the Put Online button to allow remote share but now I want to disable that feature help would be very much so appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You use the wampmanager menu just like when you turned it on, if you look again the menu will have changed to `Put Offline`

Chick that and it will amend the httpd.conf file and restart Apache and you will be back to local only accessn